# Advice on nested Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I am having trouble understanding this nested loop and how it works. In particular why does parameter 'a' that is passed to function bar have the value 3?

```
function foo() {
  function bar(a) {
    i = 2; // change value of i in enclosing scope
    console.log(a + i);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bar(i); // infinite loop
  }
}
foo();
```

Can someone explain why is bar called with 3? I thought first time bar is called it would be zero from inital value of i in the enclosing for loop?

I know this is an infinite loop where a + i always prints 5
I know that the  value of parameter a passed to bar is always 3
I know that the value of i in function bar is always 2

Can someone walk me through one repeitition of this infinite loop, explaining the order in which things occur.

Comment: The first iteration actually prints `2` (0 + 2). Each following iteration prints `5` (3 + 2) since `i` is reset to `2` each time `bar` is called and is then incremented by `1` by the for-loop.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I get it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Lexical Environment” is a specification object: it only exists “theoretically” in the language specification to describe how things work. We can’t get this object in our code and manipulate it directly.

You can imagine it's like an object where function looking for a variable

```
function foo() {
  // 1. Lexical Environment foo { i = undefined}
  function bar(a) {
    // 3. Lexical Environment bar (inner) {a = 0}
    i = 2; // 4.  There is no i in Lexical Environment  bar, so it follows the reference to the outer Lexical Environment foo
    //     and finds it there. And is changing Lexical Environment foo { i = 2}
    // 5  Lexical Environment foo = { i = 2}
    console.log(a + i); // On the all steps i = 2
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // 2. Lexical Environment foo { i = 0}
    // 6. On the second and next step in loop i = 3 because we use Lexical Environment foo and add +1 to i
    // Lexical Environment foo  i + 1  { i = 3} and its is repeating again on next step
    bar(i);
  }
}
foo();

// Below 2 examples how you can fix this example

function foo() {
  // 1. Lexical Environment foo  {i = undefined}
  function bar(a) {
    // 2. Lexical Environment bar (inner) = {a = 0, i = undefined}
    var i = 2; // 3. Lexical Environment bar (inner) = {a = 0, i = 2}

    console.log(a + i); // uses only Lexical Environment bar
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // 2. Lexical Environment foo = { i = 0}
    // 4. Lexical Environment foo  i + 1 =  { i = 1}
    bar(i);
  }
}
foo();

function foo() {
  // 1. Lexical Environment foo  = {}
  function bar(a) {
    // 2. Lexical Environment bar (inner) = {a = 0}
    i = 2; // 3. Lexical Environment foo (outer) = {i = 2}

    console.log(a + i); 
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // 2. If we use let, block have own Lexical Environment for = { i = 0}
    // 4. Lexical Environment for  i + 1 =  { i = 1}
    bar(i);
  }
}
foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see if you run this slightly modified snippet, on the first iteration, `bar()` *is* called with 0, since `var i = 0` sets the value of `i` to be zero before the first iteration.

```js
function foo() {
  function bar(a) {
    i = 2;
    console.log("a:", a, "| i:", i, "| a + i:", a+i);
  }
  for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < 10, j < 3; i++, j++) {
    bar(i);
  }
}
foo();
```

So step by step, as you asked:

**Step 0:**

- `foo()` is called.
- `function bar()` is initialized.
- Loop is reached, `i` is initialized and set to 0.

**Step 1:**

- `bar(i)` is called, with `i` = 0.
- Inside `bar()`, `a` is set to 0.
- `i` from outer scope (`foo()`) is set to 2.
- Log prints `a + i`, 0 + 2, printing 3.
- `bar()` ends, returning execution to for loop.
- `i++` is run, setting `i` to 3.
- `i < 10` is checked, 3 is less than 10, so loop continues.

**Step 1 + n:**

- `bar(i)` is called, with `i` = 3.
- Inside `bar()`, `a` is set to 3.
- `i` from outer scope (`foo()`) is set to 2.
- Log prints `a + i`, 3 + 2, printing 5.
- `bar()` ends, returning execution to for loop.
- `i++` is run, setting `i` to 4.
- `i < 10` is checked, 4 is less than 10, so loop continues.

(Repeat to infinity)